# VS Code: launch: program 'c:\Windows\System32\projects\helloworld\build\Debug\outDebug' does not exist

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I recently downloaded VS Code and have been encountering this error (launch: program 'c:\Windows\System32\projects\helloworld\build\Debug\outDebug' does not exist) every time I try to debug my program. I can run my program, but when I click debug, I get this error code. I followed all the instructions on VS Code's [instruction page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw). I have downloaded the correct compiler, successfully built and ran the code, installed the correct extensions etc, but the website did not mention this error at all.
[image]

I have searched up many articles online but none of them worked/I did not understand them. I also uninstalled and reinstalled VS Code and MSYS2 G++ Compiler many many times, but the same error kept appearing. Any help will be appreciated.

The comments have pointed out that my `launch.json` might have an error. For reference, here is my `launch.json` file:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "C/C++ Runner: Debug Session",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "externalConsole": true,
      "cwd": "c:/Windows/System32/projects/helloworld",
      "program": "c:/Windows/System32/projects/helloworld/build/Debug/outDebug",
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Either the program didn't build correctly. Or there's an error in your launch configuration file `launch.json`. Please show us both your `tasks.json` and `launch.json` file.

Comment: Don't put files or directories in the *system* directory `c:/Windows/System32/`! Do it in your own users home directory instead. By putting it in a system directory chances are there's a third alternative: Your anti-virus is interfering. Generally, you should *never* need to touch or even look into the `C:\Windows` directory yourself.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks, for some reason that solved the problem. I can never understand VS Code.